# Can a single Heroku app handle both http and https domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, heroku, https

I have a single Ruby on Rails app running on Heroku that has about 50 domains pointing to it.

All of the domains are http.

There is a "master" app that I would like to convert to https.

Examples:

Master app is:

- http://CappedSports.com

"child apps" :

- http://RatedR.press
- http://SharkyGroup.com
- http://CycloneEdge.com

Is it possible on Heroku to have the "master app" accept https and not affect the "child apps"?

Thank you!

Just of note: I do a quick check of the `request_url` in `ApplicationController` to determine if it is a "child app" and render the appropriate view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible. You just don't want to `config.force_ssl = true`, as that'll redirect all your apps to HTTPS.

You really should serve *all* your apps over HTTPS, however, as any information sent over the wire will be visible to others.

Comment: Yes. My issue is that many non-tech people buy domain names and point to my app. I like to make set up very easy. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Is there any way to force ssl on just my "master app"?

Comment: You'll probably want some logic in a [before_action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) which redirects the HTTPS URL of your master app when that is the map which has been detected.